# How to set a Richards model for epidemiology?

Tags: modeling, epidemiology, epidemic-curve

I have read in several papers that the Richards equation

[image]

is one of the most popular choices to model epidemiologic data. I translated the equation in R's terms:

```
y = r * x * (1-(x/k)^a)
```

with y being the infected number at time t, x being the infected at time t-1.
I got the COVID cumulative infections from China between 10 and 23 January and I tried to assign some initial value but I can't find values that fit the data:
[image]

Since the data is not sigmoid, I even tried to extend the period up to present-day but, again, I get linear fitting instead that sigmoid:

[image]

Even with optimization using  nonlinear least squares, I do not obtain a curve but a line:
[image]

Is the Richards equation truly a good choice for these data (in particular in the first case)?

What values turn this equation from a line to a curve?

Is the translation of the equation into code correct?

Thank you

Comment: "the best model for epidemiologic data" is not even true for infectious diseases, let alone, e.g., mortality data, birth data, chronic disease data, addictive behavior data, etc.

Comment: OK, so let's say "one of the models suggested"

Comment: This paper may be of some use...Generalized logistic growth modeling of the COVID-19 outbreak in 29 provinces in China and in the rest of the world  https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.05681

Comment: Thank you, I'll read it. From other papers, I gather that the data must be S-shaped, thus I can't use the early stage of the infection (first figure) but the whole data set (second figure). The bottom line, however, is that the Richards should give an S-shaped curve...

Comment: Note the differences in shape between Richards' and logistic growth curves. Logistic curves are finite and short in both ramping up and reaching the limit where Richards curves have much longer tails.